# Error when following the quickstart gmail api with node js

Tags: node.js, gmail-api

I'm using `nodejs` and created an app using the angular framework. I followed the quick start guide to the gmail `api`. Started a project in the google developer console, enabled gmail `api`, downloaded the `OAuth2` json file, installed the google `api` library, made an `index.js` file in my project with the code the quick start says to paste in, moved my `credenstial.json` file to my project, and when i put "node ." in the terminal i get this message:

```
Error loading client secret file: [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\edara\bvt-code-academy\personal-projects\google\google-app\credentials.json'] {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'open',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\edara\\bvt-code-academy\\personal-projects\\google\\google-app\\credentials.json'
}
```

Did anyone else have the same problem or know what I did wrong?

Comment: `credentials.json` needs to be in the folder `C:\Users\edara\bvt-code-academy\personal-projects\google\google-app\credentials.json`

Comment: @RafaGuillermo the json file is already in that folder.  which is why I don't understand what its asking me to do. i tried looking up the error but nothing helpful.

Comment: @RafaGuillermo i figured it out. I just had to change the file name to credentials.json because the file name was whatever it was named when I downloaded it

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a client secret from google cloud platform following the google docs. then copy paste that JSON credentials for oAuth into credentials.json.

Then you will be prompted with the URL to authorize.